Azure DevOps task fails to checkout disabling shallow
In my Azure DevOps pipeline I'm using GitVersion to determine a version number for my software system using semantic versioning. At this time, the GitVersion task fails because my repo is shallow. To overcome this problem, I can add a fetchDepth of 0 to disable shallow clones, however... It fails:
Below is a fraction of my (Yuck Yaml) pipeline:
- checkout: self
  fetchDepth: 0
  fetchTags: true
  persistCredentials: true
  clean: false
  displayName: Checkout and clean

- script: git -C $(Pipeline.Workspace)/s rev-parse --is-shallow-repository
  displayName: Check

As you can see, I do a repo with fetchDepth of 0 but still, the following script (git -C...) reports the repo is shallow:

How can I fetch from my repo with truely disabling shallow repository so GitVersion can do its job?

Hi Eduard, the same git command output false on MS-Hosted agent. If you set checkout clean as true would the issue persist?

Hi @AlvinZhao-MSFT, thanks for your reply. Yes, the clean option doesn't seem to make a difference

Hi @EduardKeilholz, I could somehow reproduce the issue and I noticed the shallow file keep appearing in the .git directory. If possible, would you please try adding workspace: clean: all to your YAML definition like in this document?

@AlvinZhao-MSFT - Workspace clean works like a charm.

I could reproduce the issue if I set checkout with fetchDepth: 0, after several runs with fetchDepth set to 1. And I noticed the shallow file kept appearing in the .git directory when the issue was reproduced.

For this, I tried to clean the pipeline workspace to make sure the .git folder in the source directory was removed before the checkout step.
workspace:
  clean: all

steps:
# - script: sleep 30s
- checkout: self
  fetchDepth: 0
  fetchTags: true
  persistCredentials: true
  clean: false
  displayName: Checkout and clean
- script: |
    echo "================1. Check if shallow fetch================"
    git -C $(Pipeline.Workspace)/s rev-parse --is-shallow-repository
    echo "================2. Check YAML definition================"
    cat YAML/CheckoutShallow.yml
    echo "================3. Check shallow file in .git================"
    tree .git
  displayName: Check

Or if you prefer, you may consider removing the shallow file with a simple script.
- script: |
    if test -f "$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/.git/shallow"; then
      echo "Remove shallow file."
      rm "$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/.git/shallow"
    else
      echo "No shallow file found!"
    fi
  displayName: 'Clean shallow'


Yes, I tested yesterday already and saw Workspace Clean seems to solve the job. Now I have had several runs of the pipeline and all without this issue. I think this one is solved. Thanks for the help!

Glad to know the answer to use workspace clean works for you and thank you for taking time to share the update. Happy coding and cheers!

Yes, and do combine it with a clean: true in the checkout step. Both need to be in place, then it works, just now found this issue: https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-agent/issues/4419
